# When i am using compodoc tool to generate documentation for angular app , i am getting overview section as blank.Exact error is mentioned at the end

Tags: angular, compodoc

Used the following command to install compodoc

```
npm install -g @compodoc/compodoc
```

Now i used the following command to run tsconfig.app.json file

```
compodoc -p tsconfig.app.json -s
```

I got the Url where to get the documentation as->http://127.0.0.1:8080.Ican open this URL.But the overview section is balnk.I am not getting any information about the module or injectable part.The exact error(precisely warning) i am getting on the termial is given below

> (node:19816) V8: C:\Users\sourav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@compodoc\compodoc\node_modules\viz.js\viz.js:33 Invalid asm.js: Function definition doesn't match use

Comment: What happens if you run **compodoc -p tsconfig.json -s** i.e. without the .app extension?

Comment: yes colin .you are correct..if i run the command without .app extension its working fine..Now i can see all the things.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You must be having files Array in tsconfig-app.json. Move content of that files array into includes array. if that array is empty just remove it. then try running this command.

Comment: This actually explains what is happening and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

use tsconfig.base.json instead of tsconfig.app.json

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue of a blank overview. I had no issue with an almost identical project from a little over a year ago. However, Juan Davir Burgos Oquendo answer solved my problem. I used tsconfig.base.json instead of tsconfig.json and got the documentation I expected. (I would have just commented in his comment, but don't have the 50 reputation required.)